# State is blank in react js render function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react js . The problem is when setting the state value in menuitem and accessing them gives blanks while manually setting the value works fine.
this the code snippet i have.

```
    //class definition
        class DowntimeAcknowledgeComment extends React.Component{
         constructor(props){
                super(props);
         this.state = {
                    comment: '',
                    startTime : Datetime.moment(),
                    endTime   : Datetime.moment().add(2, 'h'),
                    ...
        };
         //functon binding
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        }
        //handle change function
        handleChange(event, index, value){
                        this.setState({value: value});
            }

//render function
     render(){

        <div className="inline-block ">
                          <div className="width-80px margin-4px">Downtime for:</div>
                            <MuiThemeProvider >
                                <SelectField  value={this.state.value}  onChange={this.handleChange} >
                                      <MenuItem defaultValue={this.state.endTime} primaryText="2 Hours" />
                                      <MenuItem value={this.state.startTime} primaryText="8 Hours" />
                                      <MenuItem value="manual" primaryText="Manual"/>
                                </ SelectField>
                                </ MuiThemeProvider>

    <p>hello there {this.state.startTime}</p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.setState({value: event.target.value})`?

Comment: Try logging the values of 'index', 'event', and 'value' to the console and make sure you are assigning the desired value.

Comment: @SachiTekina your suggetion seems to work but the defaultValue={this.state.endTime} is still coming as undefined :/

Comment: @RohitKumar you can set that in state actually.It is undefined because it is triggered in an `onChange` event.

Comment: @SachiTekina Can you tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: @RohitKumar Does the default `value` is the same as `endTime`?

Comment: @SachiTekina The selected Field is not getting updated when selecting a menuitem in dropdown.

Comment: @RohitKumar see my answer, try if it helps. It must be your `handleChange` function.

Comment: i Think the problem is with value: Datetime.moment().add(2, 'h'). if i set this to like value:1 and if i access the menuitem all works perfectly fine <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="2 Hours" />  in my above code . so i think the value set using datetime like the above code is having some kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultValue` is not available in material-ui `SelectField`

change that to `value`

```
<MenuItem value={this.state.endTime} primaryText="2 Hours" />
```

if you want default Selected value as 2 Hours time, set the state `value` same as `endTime`

```
this.state = {
    comment: '',
    startTime: Datetime.moment(),
    endTime: Datetime.moment().add(2, 'h'),
    value: Datetime.moment().add(2, 'h')
    ...
};
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler accepts two extra arguments that it won't receive, as event handlers (including Reacts') only receive a single argument, the event object.

You can nevertheless obtain the `value` information from that event object, like this:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}
```

Which coincidentally mimics [one of React's examples on forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field), `SelectField` has no `defaultValue` properties use `value` instead.

```
<SelectField  value={this.state.value}  onChange={this.handleChange} >
    <MenuItem value={this.state.endTime} primaryText="2 Hours" />
    <MenuItem value={this.state.startTime} primaryText="8 Hours" />
    <MenuItem value="manual" primaryText="Manual"/>
</ SelectField>
```

Also, you can set the initial value of `value` by, given that the default value is the same as `endTime`

```
this.state = {
  comment: '',
  startTime: Datetime.moment(),
  endTime: Datetime.moment().add(2, 'h'),
  value: Datetime.moment().add(2, 'h')
}
```

Your `handleChange` function should be:

```
handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});
```

using arrow function.

Comment: npm: '2.14.7',
 node: '4.2.2',

Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (183:13) > 183 | handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});